# HashMap key is Utf8?

Tags: java

I am in an interesting situation. I basically have been given a `Map` generic and I knew the key seemed like a String. 
The `Map` (foolingly) looks like:

```
{
   "key1": 31.0
}
```

When I did

```
 for(Object o : map.keySet()){
   System.out.println(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
 }
```

The output is `Utf8`

So when I do `System.out.println(map.containsKey("key1"))` it prints false.

How can I retrieve this value properly?

Comment: Create a Utf8 object with the value key1, assuming it has the appropriate methods for lookup in the map.

Comment: How is `map` created? What is it? A JSON parser would normally have create a map with `String` as the key, so it's certainly not that.

Comment: Could you provide result of `System.out.println(map.getClass().getName())`?

Comment: What is `Utf8`? Does it have an `equals()` method that works for `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this looks stupid, but it should solve your problem. Assuming, that class Utf8's toString() method returns "key1" for the key you're searching for.

```
Object value;
for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
    if ("key1".equals(o.toString()) {
        value = map.get(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do have the class Utf8 in your classpath, maybe it provides a constructor or builder to create a key of type Utf8 your can use to call get method